# xcode: how to detect sdk at compile time

Tags: xcode

I'm aware that the macros in Availability.h are used for sdk detection.  But they result in *_attribute_* type declarations which I don't know how to use for my purpose.

I would like to be able to use regular defines like this:

```
 #include "Availability.h"

 #if IS_USING_SDK(__MAC_10_10)
 do some declarations here
 #endif

 #if CURRENT_SDK < __MAC_10_12
 do some declarations here
 #endif
```

Any help on this?

edit: I'm using C++

Comment: What is your final purpose exactly? Because some case should be solve with `respondsToSelector:`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, my final purpose is to determine if QTKit is available.  I'm using a camera class that uses QuickTime and it not in the 10.12 sdk.  We are supposed to use avfoundation, but the library has not been converted yet.  Those who are using our software and compile on 10.12 need to have the camera disabled.  I edited the op to say I'm using C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use preprocessor directives like this:

```
#include <AvailabilityMacros.h>
#if defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_12) && MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_12
// code that requires the 10.12 or later SDK
#endif
```

or its opposite:

```
#if !defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_12) || MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_12
// code for SDKs 10.11 and earlier
#endif
```

There's a newer availability-macros header, Availability.h, that defines differently-named macros:

```
#include <Availability.h>
#if defined(__MAC_10_12) && __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __MAC_10_12
// code that requires the 10.12 or later SDK
#endif

#if !defined(__MAC_10_12) || __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < __MAC_10_12
// code for SDKs 10.11 and earlier
#endif
```

Comment: When I set my base sdk to 10.11, MAC_OSX_VERSION_10_12 remains defined

Comment: And? Why is that a problem? Also, how are you setting the base SDK to 10.11?

Comment: Oops, I should have said MAC_OSX_VERSION_10_12 remains UNdefined whether I set the sdk to 10.11 or 10.12.   I'm setting the base sdk from the list presented in 'Base SDK' in the 'Build Settings'.

Comment: Your answer works if I replace MAC_OSX_VERSION_10_12 with __MAC_10_12

Comment: I edited my answer. There are two different styles of availability macro header. If one pulls in a framework header (e.g. `<CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>`) rather than directly Availability.h, then either approach works, which is why I never noticed.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to see if __MAC_10_12 is defined.  This will indicate that the sdk is at least 10.12 which is all I really need anyway.